# DeleteCases that match partially

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have a list of strings L , L2= "some_text-to-delete" and I want to delete
all the Li that match with "text" or "delete" 
DeleteCase only gives the ones that match exactly...

Comment: Use `StringMatchQ` and string patterns: `DeleteCases[yourlist,z_/;StringMatchQ[z,___~~"text"~~___,IgnoreCase->True]` etc

Comment: What the z_/ does?

Comment: z_ is a pattern. /; is a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

let `list={"element1","element2","text","text","element5"}`

```
DeleteCases[list, x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, "*text*", IgnoreCase -> True]]    

Select[list, StringFreeQ[#, "text", IgnoreCase -> True] &]    

Extract[list,Position[list,x_String/;StringFreeQ[x,"text",IgnoreCase->True]]]
```

> {"element1", "element2", "element3"}

For a timing test, if we do `list2 = Flatten@Table[list, {100000}];`

```
(t1=DeleteCases[list2,x_/;StringMatchQ[x,"*text*",IgnoreCase->True]])//AbsoluteTiming//First
(t2=Select[list2,StringFreeQ[#,"text",IgnoreCase->True]&])//AbsoluteTiming//First
(t3=Extract[list2,Position[list2,x_String/;StringFreeQ[x,"text",IgnoreCase->True]]])//AbsoluteTiming//First
t1==t2==t3
```

> True
>
> 0.624
>
> 0.882
>
> 1.110

So t1 is the best.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, it really help me,you do know how to teach :)